# How Impliment Drag and Drop Website/Form Building System using javascript?

Tags: angularjs, drag-and-drop

I have made many web app project,,, now i would like to create a website and form building system using drag and drop with row and column feature. i dont know its technique... the basic for it.. i have used it many in wordpress.. somebody provide me some valuable info regarding it.  I would like to use it in Angularjs.

- which is the best plugin for it?
- how i implement columns and rows like 1/5, 1/3, 1/4 like in visual composer.
- how i create draggable module with imbuild html codes?

kindly note, i want basic info. just tips.

Comment: I really cannot grasp what you wanna do but if you just need drag and drop functionality of any type inside an angular app this module works like a charm https://github.com/marceljuenemann/angular-drag-and-drop-lists

Comment: Yeah... it is the answer.. i am searching for it many days,, it support many features.. Very Thanks